# I want to remove the groupView of an ExpandableListView when there is no childView in it

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Forgive me on my question way and my English . I want to remove the **groupView** of my **ExpandableListView** when there is no **childView** for it .I get my **Expandedable childView** through using **retrofit 2**.
Please be patient with me because I have a little skills in developing android :)

Here is my **ExpandableListView Adapter** code

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context _context;
private List<Headers> _listDataHeader; 
private HashMap<Headers, List<FixturesObject>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<Headers> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<Headers, List<FixturesObject>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosition);
}


@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Headers headers = (Headers) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);


        lblListHeader.setText(headers.getNameLeague());
        imageView.setImageResource(headers.getImageID());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    FixturesObject fixturesObject =(FixturesObject) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    TextView HomeTeamName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.home_team_name);

    HomeTeamName.setText(fixturesObject.getMatchHometeamName());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: That is way too much code. Reduce it to only show where your problem is.

Comment: This is my Adapter @lolbas . How can I reduce it if there is someone want to see my adapter ?

Comment: Unlikely someone will want to look through entire class content, especially since it is poorly formatted.

Comment: I edited it . Is this a good way to show my adapter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to edit `getGroupView` to return an empty FrameLayout with 0dp height if `getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0` and use the current code if it does have children.

Comment: I used setVisibility(View.GONE); and it worked at first . But when I closed my app and reopen it ,all groupViews are gone .

Comment: Did you remember to `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` when it wasn't empty?

Comment: It works , Thank you but when I close my app and reopen it , It seems header are Gone but then they appear . Is there away to prevent this thing ?

Comment: Your original thought of using setVisibility might be the way to go, just make sure you setVisibility in both cases because you might be re-using a view via the convertView parameter. 

In any case, to debug the matter, you could try not re-using the convertView parameter and always and inflate a new view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I marked it as an accepted answer . Another question please , is there a way to make the groupView disappear ?

Comment: Another approach you could take is just filter your data to remove any group that doesn't have children.